# Parsing error messges from nginx log to stackdriver with google-fluend

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, fluentd, stackdriver

We trying to set up alerting by parsing nginx error, and we need only messages with [error] level. (`[error] 27720#27720: *29765923 access forbidden by rule, client: blalbablab`). Main goal is to not send in gcp stackdriver logs that we don't need (decrease logs storage space using). So i created google-fluend with logs streaming, but i'm stuck with parsing error messages. Here is my config.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  tag nginx-error
  path /var/log/nginx/error.log
  format multiline
  format_firstline /^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \[\w+\] (?<pid>\d+).(?<tid>\d+): /
  format1 /^(?<time>\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \[(?<log_level>\w+)\] (?<pid>\d+).(?<tid>\d+): (?<message>$      multiline_flush_interval 3s
  #<parse>
    #@type regexp
    #expression (\s\[error+\])
    #time_key name
    #types id:integer
  #</parse>
</source>
```

Is this correct to using parse with regexp rules in this case? Please help me with this.

Comment: What is your complete use-case? Are you further processing the logs or simply relaying them to some output target? If the purpose is just relaying the `[error]` logs then you can simply use [grep](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/grep) filter for this. But, as you mentioned *parsing*, it sounds like there's more to this. Also, please add a couple of complete sample logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing, I got a working version.

```
 <source>
  @type tail
  format /^(?<message>.*\[error\].*)$/
  path /var/log/nginx/error.log
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/nginx-error.pos
  read_from_head true
  tag nginx-error
</source>
```